# How to collect error message from stderr using a daemonized uwsgi?

Tags: python, logging, flask, uwsgi, stderr

I run my uwsgi with `--daemonzie=~/uwsgi.log`.

I use flask. In my flask app, if I print some message into `stdin`, it will show on `uwsgi.log`. If I print to `stderr`, `uwsgi.log` won't show these message. How should I enable uwsgi to collect message from `stderr`.

The major problem is that I can not let uwsgi.log collect the exception track after I catch some exceptions in my flask app.

Answer (score 8):

Flask is catching your exceptions, make sure, you set `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` in config.

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True

@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Uwsgi logging can be set with

```
  --logto /var/log/uwsgi/app.log
```

or use [`logto2`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Logging.html#basic-logging-to-files) flag if if you want to separate `stdout` from `stderr`.

There's also possibility of setting loggers plugin (forward to syslog, etc.), however these plugins have to be compiled into uwsgi.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for worker threads. I have enabled that configuration option, set `debug=True` and the worker threads are only logging my `stdout` to `/var/log/uwsgi/%n.log`